# Print dictionary to file using pandas DataFrame, but changing dataframe format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, format

I have a dictionary of dictionaries I want to print into a csv file. I came across a way to do this using pandas.DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'foo': {'A':'a', 'B':'b'}, 'bar': {'C':'c', 'D':'d'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

#df.to_csv(path_or_buf = r"results.txt", mode='w')
```

This gives me a formatted result like so:

```
   bar  foo
A  NaN    a
B  NaN    b
C    c  NaN
D    d  NaN
```

I expected (and would like to have) a DataFrame that instead looks like:

```
foo  A    a
foo  B    b
bar  C    c
bar  D    d
```

I'm new to manipulation of dataframes, so I'm not sure how to change the formatting - would I do it in the DataFrame argument? Or is there a way to change it once the dictionary is already a df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `stack`

```
df.stack()
Out[91]: 
A  foo    a
B  foo    b
C  bar    c
D  bar    d
dtype: object
```

That is multiple index

```
dict = {'foo': {'A':'a', 'B':'b'}, 'bar': {'A':'a','C':'c', 'D':'d'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.stack()
Out[93]: 
A  bar    a
   foo    a
B  foo    b
C  bar    c
D  bar    d
dtype: object
df.stack().reset_index()
Out[94]: 
  level_0 level_1  0
0       A     bar  a
1       A     foo  a
2       B     foo  b
3       C     bar  c
4       D     bar  d
```

Comment: This answers my original question, but I noticed an issue - if there are two values shared (e.g. foo and bar both have 'A'), the dataframe leaves a blank instead of putting two A's in consecutive rows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Liquidity that is multiple index , you can reset_index() :-)